# React Native - Vertical align image with resizeMode "contain"

Tags: react-native

When an image has a resize mode "contain" it seems to align/justify the actual image in the center, the image content however is aligned/justified at flex start.

```
<Image resizeMode="contain" ...>
<Text>Title</Text>
</Image>
```

With the following I'm seeing the text appearing above the image.

Is there any way to vertically align the contained image to top ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Your post is the only reference I've found online to this problem. Thanks for sharing any additional info you have.

Comment: The same problem for me. But it will be fine if I replace **Image** with other component. Why **Image** is so special?

Comment: I think the effect Kyle is looking for is achieved on the web with the CSS property background-position (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position). I'm also looking to solve this issue. When using cover or contain I don't always want the image centered vertically and horizontally within the view.

Comment: fyi, background-position is not supported by react native :/

Comment: This is so dumb. Such a basic requirement, and it's not supported by React Native.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Using `resizeMethod="resize"`

I've found a solution that doesn't requires any extra tags or tricks. Just one single prop.

**Lore**

I had the same issue because my image on remote is @3x the regular size. And once loaded on the phone with `{ height: 100, width: 300, resizeMode: 'contain' }` styling values, it centered automatically.

**Example**

To fix it, I've just added the prop `resizeMethod` like the following :

```
<Image
  style={{ height: 100, width: 300, resizeMode: 'contain' }}
  source={{ uri: 'https://www.fillmurray.com/900/300' }}
  resizeMode="contain"
  resizeMethod="resize"
/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work with percentage height / width, only hardcoded values.

Comment: AFAIK, when I've tried doing this it haven't worked with percentage at all, vertical align issues set aside.

Comment: @ZacharyDahan Seems to be an Android method only: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemethod-android

Comment: When I've coded this snippet, I was working on an iOS app only. `resizeMode="contain"` is an iOS prop and _should_ be the one doing the trick.

Answer (score 11):

I was able to simulate CSS backgroundPosition using the following code:

```
<View style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }}>
  <Image src={{ uri: imageURI }} style={{ height: /*adjust_as_needed*/, resizeMode: 'cover' }} />
</View>
```

Because of the **overflow: 'hidden'** on the View the heigh of the image can be adjusted without seeing the extra height of the image. You'll need to user 'cover' rather than 'contain' for the resize mode as well otherwise you'll end up with a centered image that isn't as wide as the View container if you set the height of the image too large.

In the top example below the Image height (blue dotted line) is larger than the bottom example and therefore the center line of the image sits lower in the view. By reducing the height of the image (blue dotted line) in the second example, the center line of the image moves up in the view.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You need to use styles on your Image to set the vertical alignment you want.

```js
var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={{uri: "http://placekitten.com/300/505"}} style={styles.image}>
          <Text style={styles.instructions}>
            Hello !
            </Text>
        </Image>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  image: {
    height: 500,
    justifyContent: "space-around",    //  <-- you can use "center", "flex-start",
    resizeMode: "contain",             //      "flex-end" or "space-between" here
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    fontSize: 25,
  },
});
```

See https://rnplay.org/apps/9D5H1Q for a running example

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. Unfortunately this doesn't quite solve the problem I'm facing. I've added an example at https://rnplay.org/apps/9qKrYA.

Notice that even with flex-start the actual image is still in the center.
http://prntscr.com/8wc3cf

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Could you draw it in paint or something? Do you want to have you images on top of the rows (vertically) with white space below them?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the same thing. The best way I found to accomplish this was to explicitly give the height or width of the image. Then, by wrapping your image in an other component, you can use justifyContent to have full control on the position of the image.

It's true that you might not always have the width or height of the image. However, quite often (especially is using resizeMode: 'contain') you want to set the height or width relative to something. I wanted the height to be equal to the width of the viewport. Here is the solution that I used:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-start' }}>
    <Image
      source={{ uri: imagePath }}
      resizeMode="contain"
      style={{ height: vw(100) }}
    />
 </View>
```

The vw is a helper function that comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34981772/5059407) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple. First find height of the screen:

```
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height
```

Now go to your style property and set the **marginVertical** prop to (**height / 4**) below:

```
<Image source = {// some url} resizeMode = 'contain' style = {width: '100%', height: height/2, marginVertical: height/4}
```

Now your image will be vertically centered.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same issue and none of the suggested solutions worked for me. An image with `resizeMode="contain"` setting always gets centered and ignores the `justifyContent` setting of the outer container.

I managed to "fix" this by setting both `width` and `height` of the image to `undefined` and also specifying its `aspectRatio`:

```js
    <View
      style={
          justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        }}
    >
      <Image
        source={require('./img/source.png')}
        style={{
          // This is as strange as it gets. The `flex-end` setting works _only_ if I pass the image's aspect ratio
          // and `undefined` for width and height properties. If any of these are missing, the image with `resizeMode="contain"
          // will be centered vertically and ignore the `justifyContent` setting of the outer container.
          aspectRatio: 0.5622, // In my case
          width: undefined,
          height: undefined,
          resizeMode: 'contain',
        }}
      />
    </View>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to fix some of values an the other let without set. in most cases let width fixed. Be carefully with parent flex option. It could change your design.