# React native flexbox - how to do percentages || columns || responsive || grid etc

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, react-native

After working with react native on iOS for the last couple of weeks, I seem to have come across some shortcomings of flex styling... Particularly when it comes to "responsive" behavior.

For instance, lets say you want to create a view that contains cards (the metadata for these cards comes from an API). You want the cards to be 50% of the view width minus the margin & padding, and to wrap after each 2.

[image]

The current implementation I have for this view splits the returned array into rows with 2 items. The list container has `flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column`, the rows have `flex: 1` and then each card has `flex: 1`. The end result is each row has 2 columns which evenly take up half the view width.

It seems like there is no trivial way to do this in React Native styles, without using javascript to do some sort of pre-processing on the data so that it comes out styled correctly. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try "flexWrap" ?

Comment: Yes, but flexWrap only works when there is an overflow of children, which can only be triggered when there is a width property specified on the children. @niceass

Comment: And what's wrong with specifying a 50% width? Isn't that what you want anyway?

Comment: There is no concept of % in React native @niceass

Comment: Was interested in this question, and for the life of me could not get this to work using flexbox alone.  For us, we've put to use the Dimensions to calculate the window width and then can easily use 50% width, etc.  I've set up a gist with a working example of what you want, but admittedly it's a lot more verbose than I would have liked! https://gist.github.com/dabit3/72138f22120f835dfb92  .    This is what it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/z5HD3GR.png

Comment: Interesting. I was thinking this might be what it came to. We are thinking of creating a flexbox grid component that is similar to your solution if there really is no pure styles solution.

Comment: Here is is on RNPlay (which has not been up the entire day, so It may or may not load ) https://rnplay.org/apps/5vqO7g

Answer (score 15, accepted):

React Native already [has percentage support](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/3f49e743bea730907066677c7cbfbb1260677d11):

```
<View style={[style.parent]}>
    <View style={[style.child, {backgroundColor: '#996666'} ]} />
    <View style={[style.child, {backgroundColor: '#339966'} ]} />
    <View style={[style.child, {backgroundColor: '#996633'} ]} />
    <View style={[style.child, {backgroundColor: '#669933'} ]} />
</View>

var style = StyleSheet.create({
    parent: {
        width: '100%', 
        flexDirection: 'row', 
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
    },
    child: {
        width: '48%', 
        margin: '1%', 
        aspectRatio: 1,
    }
})
```

[image]

Comment: problem with height. height can not be reduced

Answer (score 24):

There may be a better way to achieve this with flexbox, but I usually define "percentage" helpers `vw` and `vh` for viewport width and viewport height, named after the CSS viewport size units of measurement:

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

function vw(percentageWidth) {
  return Dimensions.get('window').width * (percentageWidth / 100);
}

function vh(percentageHeight) {
  return Dimensions.get('window').height * (percentageHeight / 100);
}
```

To flow items in a grid, you can then calculate an appropriate size for items, accounting for margins and viewport size:

```
const COLUMNS = 3;
const MARGIN = vw(1);
const SPACING = (COLUMNS + 1) / COLUMNS * MARGIN;

const grid = {
  flex: 1,
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  justifyContent: 'flex-start'
};

const cell = {
  marginLeft: MARGIN,
  marginTop: MARGIN,
  width: vw(100) / COLUMNS - SPACING
}

return (
  <View style={grid}>
    {this.props.things.map(thing => <View style={cell} />)}
  </View>
)
```

You should only use this technique if you have a known and limited number of items - for arbitrary amount of cards, you should use `ListView` for performance reasons, and split your data set to rows manually.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution so far. Thank you for sharing @jevakallio.

Comment: Problem with this approach is that it will not work if you allow orientation to be changed.

Comment: @Joon correct - I have just published a library that makes it easier to style react native components in both landscape and portrait orientations: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-responsive-styles

Answer (score 2):

You can use justifyContent: 'space-between'

```
<View style={styles.feed}>
    <View style={styles.card} />
    <View style={styles.card} />
    <View style={styles.card} />
    <View style={styles.card} />
 </View>

feed: {
 flex: 1,
 flexDirection: 'row',
 flexWrap: 'wrap',
 padding: 16,
 justifyContent: 'space-between'  }


card: {
 backgroundColor: 'white',
 width: '48%',
 aspectRatio: 1,
 marginBottom: 16   }
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NRLX.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This might solve this

```js
<View style={{
              flex: 1,
              flexDirection: 'row',
              flexWrap: 'wrap',
            }}>
              {array?.map((item, itemIndex) => {
                return (
                  <View style={{
                    flexBasis: '50%',
                    height:OPTIONAL,
                    width:OPTIONAL
                  }}>
                   // YOUR CONTENT HERE
                  </View>
                )
              })}
            </View>
```