# React Native FlatGrid spawning content horizontally in one row outside of screen width

Tags: react-native

I am having some issues with react native FlatGrid spawning content horizontally despite setting horizontal to false. I want to create a 2 column vertical grid layout similar to [React native flexbox - how to do percentages || columns || responsive || grid etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952984/react-native-flexbox-how-to-do-percentages-columns-responsive-grid-et) with flatlist.

I was wondering if this is a bug with creating a TouchableOpacity object within each box.

Here's the code for my style sheet

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  gridView: {
    marginTop: 10,
    flex: 1,
  },
  itemContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    //justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10,
    height: 150,
    //alignItems: 'flex-end',
  },
});
```

And here's the code for rendering the flatgrid object

```
  render() {
    return (
        <ImageBackground source = {bgImage} style={styles.backgroundContainer}>
            <FlatGrid
            refreshControl={
              <RefreshControl
                refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
              />
              }   
              itemDimension={150}
              itemWidth = {WIDTH/2}
              //staticDimension={150}
              items={this.data()}
              style={styles.gridView}
              fixed={true}
              horizontal={false}
              numColumns={2}
              renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.itemContainer, { backgroundColor: 'rgba(40, 40, 40, 1)' }]}>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
            />
        </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
```

`WIDTH` variable is obtained from `Dimensions.get('window').width`

EDIT:

I just tried it with dummy data and it rendered perfectly. Could it be due to the fact that I'm performing a GET request on `componentDidMount` causing the FlatGrid to refresh again.