# How to vertically position an image in react native?

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native

I am trying to take an image and place it within width and height constraints, and the top of the image should be aligned with the top of the visible section of the image.

In other words, the image should not cropped to be centered vertically, it should be aligned to the top. I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's where I'm at now:

```
<Image
  source={{ uri: specificEvent.photo }}
  style={[
    {
      flex: 1,
      top: 0,
      width: 0.85 * width,
      height: 0.85 * width,
      borderRadius: 25,
      transform: [{ translateY: imageHeight }]
    }
  ]}
/>
```

Where translateY is moving the whole image down, instead of the image within the visible view.

For example, if you take this picture attached, the Shazam poster should be aligned to the top of the rounded view, not centered. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Did you attempt to change the image's `resizeMode`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365307/react-native-vertical-align-image-with-resizemode-contain

Comment: use resizeMode='contain'

Comment: contain resizes the image, rather than taking up the constraints. I still would like it zoomed to 100% width, just positioned differently within the frame